# Firebase notification console for a web application

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase for web push notifications, I have it succesfully configured and I can send messages using the API. I would like to use the notification console, but to use it I seem to have to add an app to get started and the only options are ios, android and unity, so how would I add a web application?, or is it the firebase notification console only for ios android and unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending notification type messages from the console is only supported for Android, iOS, and Unity/C++ (which just run on top of Android or iOS).  You'll notice that there is documentation for this for both platforms ([Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-with-console), [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-with-console), [Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/send-with-console), [C++](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/cpp/send-with-console)), but no such documentation exists in the parallel web/javascript space.

Comment: Sad, but thanks Doug. I thought I may be missing something but not.

Comment: You can always file a feature request.  I believe that this is missing from web because Firebase on web currently also does not support Analytics, which is tied to FCM.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features